# How do I trigger a router outlet in my app component from a nested component?

Tags: angular, angular-routing, angular-router

If I have a setup like this

```
app-component
|   |_navigation-component
|         |_link-component
|
|_router-outlet
```

How can I trigger the router outlet from the link component?

Normally we would have something like this when all in the same template

```
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a [router-link]="['home']">Home</a></li>
    <li><a [router-link]="['portfolio']">Portfolio</a></li>
    <li><a [router-link]="['about']">About</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>

<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

Seeing that I'm doing it more like this

```
<div>
    <nav-component></nav-component>

    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>

<!-- inside nav-component template -->
<nav>
    <link-component></link-component>
</nav>

<!-- inside link component template -->
<li>
    <a [router-link]="['home']">Home</a>
</li>
```

so far triggering the link from 2 tiers down doesn't work.  How can this be done?

**UPDATE**

I figured I'd show how I have things set up incase it's more to it than some manual way of triggering it.

`app-routing.module`

```
export const routes: Routes = [
    { path: '', redirectTo: '/home', pathMatch: 'full' },
    { path: 'home',       component: HomePageComponent },
    { path: 'examples',   component: ExamplesPageComponent },
    { path: 'howitworks', component: HowItWorksPageComponent },
    { path: 'resources',  component: ResourcesPageComponent },
    { path: 'aboutus',    component: AboutUsPageComponent }
];

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        RouterModule.forRoot(routes)
    ],
    exports: [
        RouterModule
    ]
})

export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

`link data`

```
export const LinkData: Array<LinkParams> = [
    { Link: 'Home',         Trigger: 'home',       Type: 'main' },
    { Link: 'Examples',     Trigger: 'examples',   Type: 'main' },
    { Link: 'How It Works', Trigger: 'howitworks', Type: 'main' },
    { Link: 'Resources',    Trigger: 'resources',  Type: 'main' },
    { Link: 'About Us',     Trigger: 'aboutus',    Type: 'main' }
]
//the data I'm iterating down into the link component
```

`app.component (template)`

```
<div  class="appComp-grid" [ngStyle]="{'grid': Grid.GridCode}">
    <link-container [ngStyle]="{'grid-area': Grid.GridAreas.LinkContainer}" [SiteLinks]="Links"></link-container>

    <div [ngStyle]="{'grid-area': Grid.GridAreas.BodySection, 'justify-content': 'stretched'}">
        <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </div>

    <footer-component [ngStyle]="{'grid-area': Grid.GridAreas.FooterSection}"></footer-component>
</div>
```

`link-container.component (template)`

```
<header class="linkComp-grid" [ngStyle]="{'grid': Grid.GridCode}">

    <div [ngStyle]="{'grid-area': Grid.GridAreas.MainLink, 'display': 'grid', 'grid-auto-columns': 'auto', 'grid-auto-flow': 'column'}">

        <link-component *ngFor="let a of SiteLinks" [Link]="a"></link-component>

    </div>

    <div [ngStyle]="{'grid-area': Grid.GridAreas.FeatureLink, 'grid-auto-flow': 'column', 'justify-self': 'end'}">
        <h3>Feature Link</h3>
    </div>

</header>
```

`link.component (template)`

```
<a class="linkComp-grid"
   [ngStyle]="{'grid': Grid.GridCode}"
   [routerLink]="Link.Trigger" routerLinkActive="active"
>
    <p [ngStyle]="{'grid-area': Grid.GridAreas.LinkArea, 'text-align': 'center'}">
        {{Link.Link}}
    </p>
</a>
```

Comment: Can u tell clearly what do you want ?

Comment: I just updated the question to hopefully make it clearer.

Comment: Can you show your routing and app.module , i just tested however it's working for me

Comment: just made another edit